# Warning seen when saving a maven project in Jenkins when Git as source code management is used

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and creating a maven job.
Jenkins is installed/deployed in CentOS.

**App versions:**
Jenkins: 2.401.1
Java: OpenJDK 17
Maven: 3.8.1
Git: 1.8.3.1

When 'Git' is used as Source Code Management, saving the job shows 'A problem occurred while processing the request.' in UI.

At logs, following is logged:

```
15-Jun-2023 00:02:28.913 WARNING [Handling POST /jenkins/job/test/configSubmit from XX.XX.XX.XXX : http-nio-8090-exec-2] hudson.init.impl.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler.handleException Caught unhandled exception with ID 317bece8-c320-4730-9ad3-c81937baae8c
 java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.model.AbstractProject#scm for class hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet
        at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:220)
        at hudson.model.AbstractItem.save(AbstractItem.java:619)
        at hudson.model.Job.save(Job.java:194)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.save(AbstractProject.java:288)
        at hudson.BulkChange.commit(BulkChange.java:98)
        at hudson.model.Job.doConfigSubmit(Job.java:1349)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.doConfigSubmit(AbstractProject.java:772)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:732)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:397)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:409)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:207)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.SelectionInterceptedFunction$Adapter.invoke(SelectionInterceptedFunction.java:36)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.verb.HttpVerbInterceptor.invoke(HttpVerbInterceptor.java:48)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.SelectionInterceptedFunction.bindAndInvoke(SelectionInterceptedFunction.java:26)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:140)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:558)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:770)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:900)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:289)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:770)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:900)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:698)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:248)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
        at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:129)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
        at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainFilter.doFilter(ResourceDomainFilter.java:81)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:94)
        at jenkins.security.AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.java:52)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
        at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:54)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:101)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
        at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:97)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:63)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:111)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:172)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:86)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:38)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.model.AbstractProject#scm for class hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:274)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:241)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:174)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:226)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:163)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:59)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:44)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:83)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1303)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1292)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:1265)
        at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:213)
        ... 96 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM#submoduleCfg for class hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:274)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:241)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:174)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:226)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:163)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:59)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshallField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:283)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:270)
        ... 109 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field protected transient int java.util.AbstractList.modCount accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @3b1d025f
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.buildDictionaryEntryForClass(FieldDictionary.java:176)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.buildMap(FieldDictionary.java:142)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.fieldsFor(FieldDictionary.java:80)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:167)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:206)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:163)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:50)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:59)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshallField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:283)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:270)
        ... 118 more
```

When the same job is opened after reload, the settings made can be seen. However, if any changes are made and saved again- above is seen.

I am trying resolve the error/warning seen, but haven't found any solution for this.
It would be great to get some solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not seen when Java 11 is used.